# Two functions making my game crash when running in a row

Tags: c++

I usually find answers for my problems on this forum, but this time I can't. This is why I am asking you. (Sorry in advance for the mistakes I'm doing in english or c++)

So here is my void function, it is just the start of a little game I'm making in the console. It is just showing some informations. By the way it's a french game, but I don't think that a traduction is needed to solve my problem.

```
void showIntro (Personnage a, Personnage b, Personnage c)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "VOUS ENTREZ DANS LES MINES DE LA MORIA" << endl << endl;
cout << "ENNEMIS PRESENTS : " << endl << endl;
cout << "                           " << "Orc robuste" << endl << endl << endl;
a.afficherEtatIntro ();
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "                           " << "Orc robuste" << endl << endl << endl;
b.afficherEtatIntro ();
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "                           " << "Orc robuste" << endl << endl << endl;
c.afficherEtatIntro ();
cout << endl << endl;

cout << "Le combat va commencer";
Sleep(1000);
cout << ".";
Sleep(1000);
cout << ".";
Sleep(1000);
cout << "." << endl << endl << endl;

cout << "Gimli : ";

string phraseGimli ("Je vengerai mes freres!");

for (int f = 0; f <= phraseGimli.size(); f++) // Just writing a sentence
{
    cout << phraseGimli[f];
    Sleep(100);
}

cout << endl << "Legolas : ";

string phraseLegolas ("Nous sommes avec toi mon ami");

for (int g = 0; g <= phraseLegolas.size(); g++) // Writing a sentence
{
    cout << phraseLegolas[g];
    Sleep(100);
}


cout << endl << "Aragorn : ";

string phraseAragorn ("POUR LE GONDOR");

for (int i = 0; i <= phraseAragorn.size(); i++) // Writing a sentence
{
    cout << phraseAragorn[i];
    Sleep(100);
}

}
```

And here is the other one.

```
void choixAttaque (Personnage joueur, Personnage a, Personnage b, Personnage c, string nom)
{
cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;

cout << "Qui souhaitez vous attaquer ?" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "                           " << nom << endl << endl << endl;
a.afficherEtatIntro ();
cout << endl << "Tapez 1" << endl;
cout << "                           " << nom << endl << endl << endl;
b.afficherEtatIntro ();
cout << endl << "Tapez 2" << endl;
cout << "                           " << nom << endl << endl << endl;
c.afficherEtatIntro ();
cout << endl << "Tapez 3" << endl;

int choix;

do
{

    cin >> choix;

} while (choix <= 0 || choix >= 4);


switch (choix)
{
    case 1:
        joueur.attaquer(a);
    case 2:
        joueur.attaquer(b);
    case 3:
        joueur.attaquer(c);
}



}
```

afficherEtatIntro ()

```
void Personnage::afficherEtatIntro () const
{
cout << "          " << "Vie : " << m_vie << endl;
cout << "          ";
m_arme->afficher();

}
```

m_arme means m_weapon, I used "->" because it is from a pointer. I'm new to all of this, so it can be really possible that the mistake comes from here.

When I'm using only one, it works, but when I'm using both in a row, it does that.

[first void function showing properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe3xH.png)

And then.

[Path of things in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKr4B.png)

I hope I gave the informations needed to solve the problem, and I hope it can be solved. Thanks in advance for everything, and sorry for all the mistakes I may have made in english, c++ or by linking my lines of code. ^^'
(Btw, all the "cout << endl;" looks ugly I guess, but that is just until I learn how to use Qt..)

From debugger: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."
And a picture in comment. (Need more reputation for 3 links..)

Comment: This is way too much code; step through this in a debugger, find the cause of the problem, and if you still can't figure it out post an MCVE here.

Comment: One major point would be that your switch-case doesn't have any ````break````s so if you choose 1, it would run all cases.

Comment: Is there any chance that you're exceeding the bounds of whatever your `size()` is in the for loops?  Typically you avoid `<=` when looping over something that is a `size()`.  Instead, just try '<'.

Comment: @mascoj Thanks, I changed that but the problem was not from this.

Comment: @TimReddy I tried what you said but it changed nothing. And when I only run the first function it is working well so I guess that is not the problem.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/VpOLz The picture from debugger.

Comment: You aren't showing this function... What happens when you comment out this line `m_arme->afficher();`?

Comment: @DigitalNinja It's about afficher() and afficherEtatIntro(), I've been looking for information in the debugger. The problem is probably from a pointer trying to access to something he should not access. 'void Arme::afficher() const
{
    cout << "Arme : " << m_nom << "(Degats : " << m_degats << ")" << endl;
}' m_nom is the name of the weapon, m_degats are the damage.